# jQuery, how do I check a time range?

Tags: jquery, time, range

I want to display 3 different background images according to the time of the day: one for morning from 4am to 12am one for afternoon from 12am to 6pm and one for the night from 6pm to 4pm. Im using the json server to get the time zone etc...
I tried this but doesn't work properly:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      var timezone = "Europe/London";
      $.getJSON("http://json-time.appspot.com/time.json?tz="+timezone+"&callback=?",
        function(data){
           if ((data.hour > 4) && (data.hour < 12)) {
              $('body').css("background-image", "url('dawn.jpg')").css('background-repeat', 'no-repeat');
          } 
          else if ((data.hour < 4) && (data.hour > 18)){
            $('body').css("background-image", "url('night.jpg')").css('background-repeat', 'no-repeat');
          }
          else if ((data.hour > 12) && (data.hour < 18)){
            $('body').css("background-image", "url('afternoon.jpg')").css('background-repeat', 'no-repeat');
          }

        });
      });
```

I should have something that checks the range between the times, but I don't know how to do it.

Any solution?

Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only problem I see with your code is that you should in some cases use <= and >= rather than < and >. The hours starting with 4, 12, 18 aren't covered.

Comment: Yeah thanks! but is not the only problem. I've just figured out that the 'night' statement is wrong. I need two of these, one that covers from 18 to 23 and one from 00 to 4! Thanks for your help! :)